# Could a regional tag (or a new "international" tag) be made mandatory?

Tags: feature-request, country-tags

I saw that this possibility was already mentioned  (a little over a year ago) in an answer to [this question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/do-401k-questions-all-need-the-united-states-tag), and Chris W. Rea commented that the lack of a specific regional tag should be taken to mean that the question is universally applicable.

I just don't think this is working the way it is intended; given that the majority of the site audience appears to be in the US, there are many many questions asked that are US-specific but are not given the united-states tag.

For example, I just re-tagged [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11561/can-my-so-deposit-a-check-made-out-to-me) with united-states. The wording of the question does not specify a location and there would be many different answers depending on the jurisdiction in question. It is evident from the OP's location that they intended the question to relate to the US, and indeed all the answers seem to apply to US-ian banking systems.

As a non-US-ian, this is probably more annoying to me than it is to the US-ian sections of the audience. I just think the idea of insisting on a regional tag (or "other-region" or "international") could usefully be reconsidered from this perspective.

Comment: I Agree with your point, however to my understanding making a specific set of tags mandateory is not a practise on the main site. Its only on meta where one tag from a set of 7 are mandetory.

Comment: We do need to *encourage* use when appropriate, and retag where the OP missed it (thanks!), but there are loads of questions where it isn't necessary and would take up a tag slot (5 max).  I'd like system support ideally, but guidance-oriented as opposed to required.

Comment: Time to get out my big annoying-location-tag-asker hammer...

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on @ChrisWRea's comment:

I don't like a system that requires a tag.  International is not the same as no-country.   I wouldn't mind if there was a prompt of some type that suggested adding a regional code, but I don't think a requirement for a country code is a good move.

Comment: I'd be happy with some prompt to remind people to add a regional tag if appropriate.

Comment: I agree, a prompt to add the region in the tags would help.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to ask a different flavor of this question - [Suggestion: Require new users to include their country in user profile](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/suggestion-country-required) 
Specifically, that new users be required to add their state/country when setting up their profile. It seems that more often than not, the new user asks a question where a country tag is needed, and it would make it easier if when looking at their profile, it's listed there.

I agree all questions don't need a location tag, which is why I propose this for profiles, not questions.

Comment: Perhaps even some verbiage on the signup page that encourages people to enter at least a country, if not anything more specific?

Comment: Sure, there may still be some questions, for example, in US, where the state law is important, but narrowing down to country would get us most of the way there.