# Suggestion: Require new users to include their country in user profile

Tags: feature-request

Any question touching on investing or taxes need to reflect a country to properly answer. Is it possible to require a country **at the time users first sign up**? Else, we are waiting for this info and can't answer until the OP comes back.

Note - I am not asking for a mandatory question-tagging. This request is that when a new user signs up, they should include their country. I am noticing that the new users don't include this, and we are often waiting for their update before we can address their question.

Comment: The above suggestion was *not* referencing questions, but new users as they signed up for SE. That would help get ahead of the curve for all future questions.

Comment: What if someone enters a garbage name as a country? Will the "country" the user enters be checked against a list of country names that are acceptable to SE sites? What if a user indicates a region in political turmoil by a country name that is not commonly accepted as a political entity? e.g. Kurdistan?

Comment: If they want a legitimate answer, I'd imagine that would be motivation to show the country whose tax laws/structure they'd like us to use.

Comment: Requiring a new user to specify a country when registering on the SE sites helps only those on money.SE who want to check where an OP is coming from, not which country's tax rules the OP wants information about. Besides, in most cases, the information would have little relevance on umpteen SE sites and be of any interest to a handful at best. So I don't expect the SE staff to jump on this as a must-have feature that must be implemented right away.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - and that may be the answer. This and the tax site are the only ones that would matter. So that may put an end to this.